# Variance of a Straight line model [time series with deterministic mean]

Tags: regression, time-series

I have been given the question -

**Consider the linear trend model:  = 0 + 1 +  + 0.5−1. You can assume 0=10, 1=0.2 and ^2=1. Find Var().**

I tried solving this question by doing this -

var() = var(0 + 1 +  + 0.5−1)

var() = var(0) + var(1) + var() + var(0.5−1)

var() = 0 + (1^2).var() + ^2 + (0.25).^2

var() = (0.04).var() + 1 + 0.25

var() = (0.04).var() + 1.25

I am not sure if this is the right approach. And if it is what exactly is the value of var()?

Any help in guiding towards the solution would be appreciated.

Comment: Please do not use codeblocks for anything that is not actual code. MathJax formatting should be used for equations, and quote formatting for quotes, if at all.

Comment: @Nij Thanks for letting me know. Changed.